# Solving a system of 50 non-linear equations - error in fn(par,...) : argument is missing

Tags: r, nonlinear-functions

I am trying to solve a system of 50 non-linear equations as follows:

Given a vector, y, which contains 49 different values, I'd like to transfer these 49 values into slightly different values in another vector, say, x such that:

```
log(x[1], y[1]) = n
...
log(x[49], y[49]) = n
x[1] + ... + x[49] = 1
```

For reasons of clarity, in the above equations `y[i]` is meant to be the base of the logarithm.

I've written the following code which, however, does not seem to work:

```
library(xlsx)
rm(list=ls())
setwd("C:/Users/.../folder")

my_data <- read.xlsx("samplefile.xlsx", 1)
y <- matrix(0:0, nrow=49,ncol=1)

for(i in 1:49) {
  if(my_data[i,1]!=0) {
    y[i,1] = 1/my_data[i,1]
    }
  }

for(i in 1:49) {
  fn <- function(x,n) {
  dummy1 <- log(x[i],y[i])-n
  dummy2 <- sum(x[1:49])-1

  return(c(dummy1,dummy2))
}
}

guess <- matrix(0.5:0.5, nrow = 50, ncol = 1)

nleqslv(guess,fn)
```

I'd expect that it solves for for `x[i]` and `n`. However, I get the following error message:

"Error in fn(par, ...) : argument "n" is missing, with no default"

Edit: Formatting

Comment: If you want to solve for `x[i]` **and** `n` both should be elements of the vector passed to `nleqslv` and to your function `fn`. See the manual of `nleqslv`.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking - how am I doing that?

Comment: You combine 2 vectors into a single vector with the base R function `c`. However your problem is unclear. You apparently have a vector `x` with 49 elements and a scalar `n`. So you need to pass a vector with 50 elements to `nleqslv`.  And you want to solve 50 equations. But you are returning a vector with two elements. Not possible with `nleqslv`. I simply do not understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to find a solution to the equation system `log(x[1], y[1]) = n  

...
log(x[49], y[49]) = n

x[1] + ... + x[49] = 1` 
where the values for the y are given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of solving your problem.

The first uses `nleqslv` for solving a system of 50 equations with 50 variables:
`x[1]` to `x[49]` and `n`. The function to be solved by `nleqslv` must return a vector containing 50 elements; the system of equations must be square.

The second simplifies your problem to a single equation in `n`.

### First solution:

```
library(nleqslv)
fn <- function(z,y) {

    x <- z[1:49]
    n <- z[50]

    f <- numeric(50)

    for( k in 1:49 ) f[k] <- log(x[k],y[k]) - n
    f[50] <- sum(x) - 1
    f
}
```

Generate some values for y and starting values for `x` and `n` and try to solve

```
y <- rep(2,49)
guess <- c( rep(.5,49), 1)

res <- nleqslv(guess,fn,y=y)
res
```

Check result:

```
# this should sum to 1
sum(res$x[1:49])
# value of n
res$x[50]
```

### Second solution:

Make use of the fact that `log(a,b) = n` implies  `a <- b^n`.
So `log(x[k],y[k])=n` is equivalent to `x[k]=y[k]^n`.
So the `x[1:49]` can be computed immediately. We only need to determine `n` from the restriction that the elements of `x` sum to 1.
This implies a simple function

```
f2 <- function(n,y) {
    x <- y^n  # gives values for x
    sum(x) - 1
}
```

And now use `uniroot` like this assuming that the values for `n` will lie between -10 and 10 and that the signs of `f2` at the endpoints have opposite sign.

```
uniroot(f2,c(-10,10), y=y)
```

You can run this code as given and check that `nleqslv` and `uniroot` give the same result for `n`.

Whether this will work for your data is up to you find out.